# Ключи массива как названия переменых

Tags: php

Как сделать ключи ассоциативного массива названиями переменных в PHP?

Имеется такой код:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
    //
}
$stmt->bind_param($type, $title, $dates);
$stmt->execute();
```

Нужно, чтоб после прохода по циклу появились переменные `$title` со значением и, соответственно, переменная `$dates`, чтоб их можно было использовать в     `$stmt->bind_param($type, $title, $dates);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то так:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
    ${$key} = $value;
}
$stmt->bind_param($type, $title, $dates);
$stmt->execute();
```

Только `$key` нужно проверять, а то мало чего.

Answer (score 0):

> нужно, чтоб ... появились переменные $title со значением и соответственно переменная $dates,

В чем проблема обратиться к ним напрямую? Точнее, зачем выполнять потенциально небезопасную операцию, если желаемый эффект достигается в пару десятков дополнительных символов?

> Как сделать ключи ассоциативного массива названиями переменных в PHP?

```
extract($params);
```

https://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php